# Extinction coefficients for narrow band filters

Tags: extinction

does anyone know the extinction coefficients for hydrogen alpha, oxygen III and sulphur II narrow band filters?
I easily found the coeffs for BVRI filters but can't find info on narrowband filters.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe some here are helpful: http://astrosurf.com/viladrich/astro/instrument/filters/Filters.html.

Comment: And more: http://www.astrosurf.com/buil/filters/curves.htm.